# How to wrap IDbTransactions in a TransactionScope

Tags: c#, transactions, transactionscope

I have several code methods that look like this:

```
using (var connection = this.connectionFactory.GetConnection())
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.Transaction = transaction;
            command.CommandText = "foo";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I now need to call several of these methods together inside an outer transaction, So I did this:

```
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    method1();
    method2();
    method3();
}
```

but its doing:

```
The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.
   at System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Activate(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

Do I need to replace the `IDbTransactions` with `TransactionScopes`?

What `TransactionScopeOption` should I use for the outer an inner scopes? Im guessing i want `RequiresNew` for the outer and `Required` for the inners?

The methods will still be called individually (i.e. without an outer `TransactionScope` as well as together, so I still need them to be transactionally safe.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are mixing technologies here and should avoid using `TransactionScope` and `DbTransaction` together because `TransactionScope` creates an implicit transaction.

So I would recommend to have your methods similar to:

```
using (var connection = this.connectionFactory.GetConnection())
{
    connection.Open();
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "foo";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Then you can call them together:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    method1();
    method2();
    method3();

    scope.Complete();
}
```

and the methods you called will share the same transaction.

Comment: this was my plan, does this leave the  top code transactionally safe? guess ill just write some test code to see!

Comment: Re: the line `command.Transaction = transaction;` -  Where does `transaction` come from?

Comment: @ChristofferLette: my bad! You don't actually need to specify it explicitly as `TransactionScope` takes care of that - updated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are doing it right.
The inner transaction is enrolled in the same scope of the outer one, and the whole thing will rollback.
To have a new transactionscope you have specify "requiresnew".(which u have mentioned)
for more clarity refer this post.
http://web.archive.org/web/20091012162649/http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/jimjohn/archive/2005/06/18/11451.aspx

Comment: that link not found , it's a pity

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what I will say, but after reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152(v=vs.80).aspx#sectionSection3

I think you should use `TransactionScope` in your sub method, but we the option `Required`. So when they are called individually, you still have a transaction, and when you call them in the upper method, the transaction sill be integrated in the ambient transaction.